# Getting Network Request Failed in React Native live server webservice

Tags: react-native

I am integrating api in React Native app with Fetch method but I am getting network request failed every time. I am new to react native. Please suggest me what I am doing wrong. Below is my code snippt:

```
 getAllCategory = () => {

        let details = {
            // 'Param1': '{keyFid:2}',
         "KeyFId":2
        };

        let formBody = [];
        for (let property in details) {
            let encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
            let encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
            formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
        }
        formBody = formBody.join("&");
        alert(formBody);
        fetch(ApiCommon.base_url+ApiCommon.get_salon_services, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {

                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: formBody
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                console.log(responseData);
                alert( "Response Body " + JSON.stringify(responseData));


            })
            .done();
    };

}
```

Comment: Are you using an emulator or real device? Seems like the network called failed - this could be due to no network being available - or perhaps you're behind a proxy. Also, I'd add a catch in the fetch call.

Comment: @JRK but when I call another api then that is getting called in emulator as well.